# Rails twbs/bootstrap-sass trouble accessing Glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I'm doing something wrong but can't figure it out.  I'm using the following versions.  Bootstrap stylesheets display fine and this gem is supposed to install the default Glyphicons, but I can't seem to get them to display.

twbs/bootstrap sass 3.3.3
rails 4.2.0

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-application
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

app/views/blah/show.html.erb

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

the above `<i>` tag should display the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples I would recommend the following for displaying the icon with Bootstrap 3.3.x:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rp67pzz9/